# Using numpy to calculate a 2d point transformation but the cross product cant calculate,why?and how?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

calculate a 2d point P(2,1) transformation in homogenous coordinate.so P is (2,1,1)T.

but NumPy error when I want to cross-product rotation matrix to P.the result should be a single column

```
import numpy as np
import math as math
p = np.reshape(np.array([2,1,1]),(3,1))
#rotate 45 matrix

r = np.eye(3)#identity
r[0,0] = math.cos(45*math.pi/180)
r[0,1] = -math.sin(45*math.pi/180)
r[1,0] = math.sin(45*math.pi/180)
r[1,1] = math.cos(45*math.pi/180)

np.cross(p,r)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldTbU.png)

Comment: Are you sure `np.cross` is the function that  you want? It's not about rotating a point,  
 Read its docs carefully, or see this Wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Comment: While your image is readable, we prefer that you include the session as text.  You'll see that many good answers include a copy-n-paste of just such a ipython/jupyter session.

Comment: Review `p`.  Is that supposed to be a (2,2) array?

Comment: p is a(1,3)array,a column vectors.I try to use np.cross to get the cross product.

Comment: `np.cross` takes 2 "vectors" and returns a third vector that is perpendicular to them.  The input vectors define a "plane" space, and result is a vector normal.  There is also a 2d interpretation.   You need to show what result you expect!